# Groups in my Ansible inventory does not work as expected

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

My yaml inventory (dev environment) is like this:

```
$> more inventory/dev/hosts.yml 

all:
  children:
    dmz1:
      children:
        ch:
          children:
            amq:
              hosts:
                myamqdev01.company.net: nodeId=1
                myamqdev02.company.net: nodeId=2
            smx:
              hosts:
                mysmxdev01.company.net: nodeId=1
                mysmxdev02.company.net: nodeId=2
    intranet:
      children:
        ch:
          children:
            amq:
              hosts:
                amqintradev01.company.net: nodeId=1
                amqintradev02.company.net: nodeId=2
            smx:
              hosts:
                smxintradev01.company.net: nodeId=1
                smxintradev02.company.net: nodeId=2
```

and when I try to ping (with `ansible -i inventory/dev -m ping all` I got the error:

```
children: | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: Could not resolve hostname children:: Temporary failure in name resolution", 
    "unreachable": true
}
ch: | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: Could not resolve hostname ch:: Temporary failure in name resolution", 
    "unreachable": true
}
all: | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: Could not resolve hostname all:: Temporary failure in name resolution", 
    "unreachable": true
}
lan: | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: Could not resolve hostname lan:: Temporary failure in name resolution", 
    "unreachable": true
}
amq: | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: Could not resolve hostname amq:: Temporary failure in name resolution", 
    "unreachable": true
}
hosts: | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: Could not resolve hostname hosts:: Temporary failure in name resolution", 
    "unreachable": true
}

etc...
```

For troubleshooting, when I execute `ansible -i inventory/dev --list-hosts all` I got:

```
hosts (16):
  all:
  children:
  dmz1:
  ch:
  amq:
  hosts:
  myamqdev01.company.net:
  myamqdev02.company.net:
  smx:
  mysmxdev01.company.net:
  mysmxdev02.company.net:
  intranet:
  amqintradev01.company.net:
  amqintradev02.company.net:
  smxintradev01.company.net:
  smxintradev02.company.net:
```

I think this command should only give the hosts, no?

I am not sure what is the issue but I followed the example from the [official doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#inheriting-variable-values-group-variables-for-groups-of-groups) and I think there's a problem with my hosts.yml file but cannot guess what I am missing.

**UPDATE**
When I correct the nodeId variables according to the answer, the list `all` is working fine. However when I try to filter by an intermediate parent this is not working:

```
ansible -i inventory/dev --list-hosts intranet
```

does not return the intranet hosts but all.

When I try: `ansible -i inventory/dev --list-hosts amq` 
only amq server are properly returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inventory file does not respect ansible's format so the yaml inventory plugin fails to parse it. Since it tries plugins in order, for some reason I don't really get it finally succeeds using the ini format and gives one host for each line in your file.

Moreover, you have to understand that a group (e.g. `smx`) contains all the hosts that have been defined in the inventory, wherever they have been defined (e.g. as a children of `intranet` or `dmz1`).

So in your actual inventory structure, `dmz1` and `intranet` both contain as children the groups `amq` and `smx` which themselves contain all hosts defined, either in the `intranet` or `dmz1` section. Hence the groups `all`, `dmz1` and `intranet` are all equivalent here and contain all hosts in the inventory.

Here is an inventory fixing your format problems and with a slightly different structure to address your expectation in terms of group targeting:

```
---
all:
  children:
    dmz1:
      hosts:
        myamqdev01.company.net:
          nodeId: 1
        myamqdev02.company.net:
          nodeId: 2
        mysmxdev01.company.net:
          nodeId: 1
        mysmxdev02.company.net:
          nodeId: 2
    intranet:
      hosts:
        amqintradev01.company.net:
          nodeId: 1
        amqintradev02.company.net:
          nodeId: 2
        smxintradev01.company.net:
          nodeId: 1
        smxintradev02.company.net:
          nodeId: 2
    amq:
      hosts:
        myamqdev01.company.net:
        myamqdev02.company.net:
        amqintradev01.company.net:
        amqintradev02.company.net:
    smx:
      hosts:
        mysmxdev01.company.net:
        mysmxdev02.company.net:
        smxintradev01.company.net:
        smxintradev02.company.net:
```

And here are a few example of how to target the desired groups of machines

```sh
$ # All machines
$ ansible -i dev/ --list-hosts all
  hosts (8):
    myamqdev01.company.net
    myamqdev02.company.net
    mysmxdev01.company.net
    mysmxdev02.company.net
    amqintradev01.company.net
    amqintradev02.company.net
    smxintradev01.company.net
    smxintradev02.company.net
$ # Intranet
$ ansible -i dev/ --list-hosts intranet
  hosts (4):
    amqintradev01.company.net
    amqintradev02.company.net
    smxintradev01.company.net
    smxintradev02.company.net
$ # all smx machines
$ ansible -i dev/ --list-hosts smx
  hosts (4):
    mysmxdev01.company.net
    mysmxdev02.company.net
    smxintradev01.company.net
    smxintradev02.company.net
$ # amq machines only on dmz1
$ # 1. Only whith patterns
$ ansible -i dev/ --list-hosts 'amq:&dmz1'
  hosts (2):
    myamqdev01.company.net
    myamqdev02.company.net
$ # 2. Using limit
$ ansible -i dev/ --list-hosts amq -l dmz1
  hosts (2):
    myamqdev01.company.net
    myamqdev02.company.net
```

Comment: Thanks it's working better, however when I want to filter on one parent like `ansible -i inventory/dev --list-hosts intranet` I got all hosts. Filtering on smx or amq works.

Comment: Answer edited. You have to change your inventory structure to acheive what you want

Comment: It clarify the provided example in the official docs which does not really solve my needs. Your example is far more clearer.